# PC not booting, no beeps following attempting to run Windows Memory Diagnostic

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

I built my PC in June as a birthday present to myself and its been nothing but a headache. I've never had half as much trouble with my previous builds combined compared to this one.

Just to give a bit of background the last issue I had was that I was getting the blue screen of death extremely frequently. After numerous tests, I worked out it was the HDD which I had transferred over so I replaced it with an SSD just for which I'm using just for booting windows. That was about three weeks ago.

This latest issue has been caused after I requested a Windows Memory Diagnostic following a Blue Screen of Death - the 1st with my new SSD. Unfortunately, my PC did not attempt/or complete the diagnostic and now will not even bring up the UEFI. Upon powering up, it sounds completely normal but I get no signal on my monitor. I'm also not hearing any beeps.

So far I have reseated everything possible bar my CPU and I'm currently doing a CMOS reset via battery but I'm not confident. I don't see how this could have happened by just asking Windows to do a Memory Diagnostic. I'm going to leave the battery out for a few hours but if it doesn't work, where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my computer is back on and I've learnt a couple of things from my experience I thought I'd share.

The first is that my motherboard an ASUS Prime B350M-A does not come with a motherboard speaker as standard. It's an optional item. Fortunately, I had one from my new case which I could use.

The CMOS reset via battery did not work but there were instructions in my motherboard's manual about shorting the Clear RTC RAM with a screwdriver. So I did it. I think this is what ultimately solved the issue but I'm not ruling out that I have a bad stick of RAM as I started off with the speaker in and no beeps which is a sign of either CPU or RAM error according to my manual. Yet my PC did go to BIOS with both RAM sticks in individually.

When I eventually got back the BIOS due to needing to set up back up, Windows went straight into the Diagnostic and as I'm currently writing this on my laptop, its halfway through.